# Is it possible to refresh a page when using Google sign-in - On login?

Tags: javascript, refresh, google-signin

I have been experimenting with Googles sign-in process. i have it almost correct, however stuck on one issue.

When i sign in - the Google button immediately changes to indicate that I am signed in. at that point, it sets a cookie with my email address. However the cookie is not immediately available. if i change pages - THEN i see the cookie.

my log out function - is working great, as i can refresh the screen & immediatly see the cookie disapear.

the test code is here:-  http://tv.kwister.com/google2.php

Ive tried various codes - & have removed my endless-refreshes (which is good..).

Can anyone advise how i 'listen' to the sign in process.

1) i am signed out
2) i press the button & the pop-up screen appears with my google Id's.

3) i select one of my Ids and the button changes to show I am signed in.

is there a test i can do at #3 to refresh the screen to a specific URL after i sign in.

the code is too big to quote here (easily).

Thank you

CODE:

```
     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
     <script>
     window.onLoadCallback = function(){
      gapi.auth2.init({
     client_id: '289042886294-mjrqers2627egmbd00mglccmme48k1hv.apps.googleusercontent.com'
});
     }
     function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
     var d = new Date();
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*250));
     var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=\/";
     }
     </script>

     <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="289042886294-mjrqers2627egmbd00mglccmme48k1hv.apps.googleusercontent.com">
     <script>
     function onSignIn(googleUser) {
     var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
     console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
     console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
     console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
     console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
     setCookie("Kwisterloggedin", profile.getEmail(), 1);
     }
     // NEW TEXT SINCE LAST FIXED
     // Listen for sign-in state changes.
     auth2.isSignedIn.listen(signinChanged);
     var signinChanged = function (val) {
     console.log('Signin state changed to ', val);
     window.location.replace("http://tv.kwister.com/google2.php?switch=1");
     }
     // END NEW TEXT


     gapi.load('auth2', function() {
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: '289042886294-mjrqers2627egmbd00mglccmme48k1hv.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     fetch_basic_profile: false,
     scope: 'profile'
     });
      // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
     auth2.signIn().then(function() {
     console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
     window.location.replace("http://tv.kwister.com/google2.php?switch=1");
     });
     });
     </script>
```

Comment: You need to post code to demonstrate your problem within the question, not an external link.  Read how to create a **[mcve]**

Comment: You might want to use postMessage? Or just keep a global function (like window.afterLogin()) which sets/refresh the session in parent window. Are you opening the google login in new window as mentioned in point 2?

Comment: is window.afterLogin() an actual function? I cant find it in google (all examples use other text - but not that exact command.  window.afterLogin()

Comment: Ive found this question - It looiks like something i want (callback - refresh a screen?) when the login button pressed ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213732/call-back-when-user-presses-gidsigninbutton