# Call back when user presses GIDSignInButton

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I am adding Google sign-in to my app. I have added GIDSignInButton in storyboard. When user clicks on that button user is sent to webpage where he can login. 
I wanted to do some checks before it happens. Is there any way that I can get a call back method before user is directed to webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create any button with same look and hook it to this action

```
@IBOutlet func btnClicked(_ sender:UIbutton) {
    // do what you want use return if checks are failed 
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Comment: I know we can do in such a way but is there no other way(like callback method or something). I wanted to use that GIDSignInButton if possible

Comment: you can hook IBAction to the button but it won't prevent navigation

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is no other way. I created custom UI and signed in using it.